# Nested environments within tabbing

Tags: environments, line-breaking, tabbing

It seems as though using nested environments within a tabbing environment along with a new line causes a `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup` error.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newenvironment{myouter}{\begin{tabbing}}{\end{tabbing}}
\newenvironment{myinner}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myouter}
        this works \\
    \end{myouter}

    \begin{myouter}
        \begin{myinner}
            so does this
        \end{myinner}
    \end{myouter}

    \begin{myouter}
        \begin{myinner}
            this doesn't \\
        \end{myinner}
    \end{myouter}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this, or what causes it?

Comment: Note that this doesn't require myouter, this works even if all myouter's are just tabbing environments, I just used outer/inner since it relates to my original problem more closely.

Comment: like all alignments cells in tabbing are a group you can not do  `\begin{myinner} \\ \end{myinner}` as the enviornment starts in one group and ends in another, you could not do that in tabular either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your inner environment sets up an environment where `\\`  has a suitable definition then it works without error.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newenvironment{myouter}{\begin{tabbing}}{\end{tabbing}}
\newenvironment{myinner}{\begin{minipage}{2cm}}{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myouter}
        this works \\
    \end{myouter}

    \begin{myouter}
        \begin{myinner}
            so does this
        \end{myinner}
    \end{myouter}

    \begin{myouter}
        \begin{myinner}
            this doesn't \\
        \end{myinner}
    \end{myouter}
\end{document}
```

With an empty environment definition then the `\\`  in the inner environment is the `\\`  from `tabbing` and that can not work as tabbing cells, like all alignment cells,  are groups You can not start an environment in one group and end it  in another, it is essentially like  this which gives the same error

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myinner}{}{}

\begin{document}
 { \begin{myinner} }  { \end{myinner} }
\end{document}
```